# Get data from mysql table which column type is " timestamp "?

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql database I've a date value which data type is `timestamp`. It's showing this value is something like this : `1415607900, 1394439900, 1412929500` etc.

Now In Html form I can pickup a date. Date value is `m/d/y` format and this date is for searching data to DB. I can pickup **Date From or Date To or Both** from this html form field.

`Date from` is searching data from **pickup date to current date.**
`Date To` is searching **all data until picktup Date**.
If `both date` value exsit then it's searching data between this 2 dates.

So how do I search data against this `timestamp` ?

Please check my following mysql query which I'm running but can't get right result. I'm highly appreciate your suggestions/solutions. Thank You.

```
if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && empty($ad_dateto)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date2 BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$date' ";   
}

if(!empty($ad_dateto) && empty($ad_datefrom)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date2 BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND '$ad_dateto'"; 
}

if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && !empty($ad_dateto)){
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date2 BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$ad_dateto' ";  
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd = contact_details Table,  
created_date2 = date column (data type : timestamp)  
$date = current date which format is m/d/y
```

**Update :**

```
/* this is for Date from*/
if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && empty($ad_dateto)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$ad_datefrom') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date') ";    
}

/* this is for Date To*/
if(!empty($ad_dateto) && empty($ad_datefrom)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('0000-00-00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$ad_dateto') "; 
}

/* this is for Date from and Date To*/
if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && !empty($ad_dateto)){
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$ad_datefrom') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$ad_dateto')";    
}
```

Comment: You would want to use FROM_UNIXTIME()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert Unix time into date time.

Here is an example 
`SELECT * FROM tbl where FROM_UNIXTIME(dt) between '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and "2014-11-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: Ok, I'm using this in my query.

Comment: Then my query is look like this : `$getSearch .= "AND cd.FROM_UNIXTIME(created_date2) BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$date' ";` is it correct ?

Comment: you code will need to change to this `"AND FROM_UNIXTIME(cd.created_date2) BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$date' ";`